# Polars Dataframe : Date conversion of Utf8 column

Tags: python, date-format, python-polars, date-conversion

I am trying to convert `utf-8` column in the DataFrame into Date format of `YYYY-MM-DD`. How to convert different date format into one format of `YYYY-MM-DD`?

```
s = pl.Series("date",\["Sun Jul  8 00:34:60 2001", "12Mar2022", "12/Mar/2022"\])

df=s.to_frame().with_columns(pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Date,fmt=('%d%m%Y' ), strict=False)) 

print(df)

┌──────┐

│ date │

│ ---  │

│ date │

╞══════╡

│ null │

│ null │

│ null │

└──────┘
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) to "combine" each formatting attempt into a single result.

```
s = pl.Series("date",[
   "Sun Jul 8 00:34:60 2001", 
   "12Mar2022", 
   "12/Mar/2022"
])

fmts = "%d/%b/%Y", "%d%b%Y", "%c"

pl.select(
   pl.coalesce(
      s.str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt=fmt, strict=False)
      for fmt in fmts
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date                │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2001-07-08 00:35:00 │
│ 2022-03-12 00:00:00 │
│ 2022-03-12 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: it doesn't worked inside pl.scan_csv().withcolumns()

Comment: @Samboo How is it not working? Can you give a code example?